# Is there a easy way to get points with black outline in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a easy way to get points with black outline in gnuplot? I'm using standard color filled point types, for example:

```
set style line 3  lc rgb '#4682B4' pt 9 ps 0.65
```

but I need to make sure that the plot will be easily readable in black & white version too. Black outlines would help, how can I add them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest "quick and dirty" solution that comes to mind is to plot the data set twice, once with the full symbol style and then with an empty symbol style. For instance:

```
plot "temp" pt 9 ps 2, "temp" pt 8 ps 2 lc 0 lw 2
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, pretty straightforward and there is probably no other option. Now, the challenge is to get a proper key entry (i.e. legend). Check this attempt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72491625/7295599