# GNUPLOT: different colors for lines and points when using "linespoints"?

Tags: colors, gnuplot, lines, points

Tried to find a solution, but did not succeed...
I want to plot my data with plottype "linespoints". The problem is: I want black lines but colored data points on the line. I only know about the "linecolor" or "lc" parameter which change the color of the line AND the points. But there is nothing like "pointcolor" (or I haven`t found it yet...).

I also thought about a workaround: Plot with plottype "lines" only the black lines and then add "points" which would plot only the colored points. This works BUT I don`t get the right legend entry...

Can you help me out? Best regards,
Sebastian

Comment: perhaps something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43997820/5351549 ?

Comment: @ewcz Thank you so much! This link helped a lot. I still have some troubles with my specific plot, so I created a new question [GNUPLOT: Merge key entries with multiplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228542/gnuplot-merge-key-entries-with-multiplot)

Answer (score 0):

Highly likely too late, but instead of linespoints plot twice the data; first as lines, then as lines using diferent linestyles, as you said.

As for the key, use " title '' " and it will not place a title for it, nor a label in the key.