# Gnuplot Plotting

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Can we plot both points with smooth csplines in one legend? If we plot them separately two legends generates with separate point and line.

I expect both point and smooth line in one legend as in case of linepoints

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I guess this could be a good question if you expand it a bit. Could you please confirm that `notitle` option does not suffice?

Comment: If `notitle` is not a solution in your case. Perhaps the solutions in this thread might help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/43996765/1328439. Note that these solutions are a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a current gnuplot (version 5.4), use `keyentry` to generate a custom entry for the plot legend.

```
plot FOO with points lt 2 notitle, \
     FOO smooth csplines with lines lt 2 notitle, \
     keyentry with linespoints lt 2 title "points + lines"
```

[image]